# Should we do learning rate decay for adam optimizer

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I'm training a network for image localization with Adam optimizer, and someone suggest me to use exponential decay. I don't want to try that because Adam optimizer itself decays learning rate. But that guy insists and he said he did that before. So should I do that and is there any theory behind your suggestion?

Comment: by learning rate decay you mean this: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR right?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

It depends. ADAM updates any parameter with an individual learning rate. This means that every parameter in the network has a specific learning rate associated.

*But* the single learning rate for each parameter is computed using lambda (the initial learning rate) as an upper limit. This means that every single learning rate can vary from 0 (no update) to lambda (maximum update).

It's true, that the learning rates adapt themselves during training steps, but if you want to be sure that every update step doesn't exceed lambda you can than lower lambda using exponential decay or whatever.
It can help to reduce loss during the latest step of training, when the computed loss with the previously associated lambda parameter has stopped to decrease.

Answer (score 52):

In my experience it usually not necessary to do learning rate decay with Adam optimizer.

The theory is that Adam already handles learning rate optimization ([check reference](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980v8.pdf)) :

> "We propose Adam, a method for efficient stochastic optimization that
>   only requires first-order gradients with little memory requirement.
>   The method **computes individual adaptive learning rates** for different
>   parameters from estimates of first and second moments of the
>   gradients; the name Adam is derived from adaptive moment estimation."

As with any deep learning problem YMMV, one size does not fit all, you should try different approaches and see what works for you, etc. etc.

Answer (score 37):

Yes, absolutely. From my own experience, it's very useful to Adam with learning rate decay. Without decay, you have to set a very small learning rate so the loss won't begin to diverge after decrease to a point. Here, I post the code to use Adam with learning rate decay using TensorFlow. Hope it is helpful to someone.

```
decayed_lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate,
                                        global_step, 10000,
                                        0.95, staircase=True)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(decayed_lr, epsilon=adam_epsilon)
```

Comment: This article suggests otherwise: https://spell.ml/blog/lr-schedulers-and-adaptive-optimizers-YHmwMhAAACYADm6F

Comment: Thanks for sharing @anujonthemove. Let me take a look.

Comment: "absolutely" is a huge red flag on this comment, reader be wary

Answer (score 16):

Adam has a single learning rate, but it is a max rate that is adaptive, so I don't think many people using learning rate scheduling with it.

Due to the adaptive nature the default rate is fairly robust, but there may be times when you want to optimize it. What you can do is find an optimal default rate beforehand by starting with a very small rate and increasing it until loss stops decreasing, then look at the slope of the loss curve and pick the learning rate that is associated with the fastest decrease in loss (not the point where loss is actually lowest). Jeremy Howard mentions this in the fast.ai deep learning course and its from the Cyclical Learning Rates paper.

**Edit:** People have fairly recently started using one-cycle learning rate policies in conjunction with Adam with great results.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the one-cycle learning rate policies you mentioned?

Comment: paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09820, community reference: https://twitter.com/jeremyphoward/status/981928159879749632?lang=en

Comment: nice relevant blog post on cyclical lr with visualization of loss landscape by another Jeremy.
https://www.jeremyjordan.me/nn-learning-rate

Comment: Are you sure Adam has a single learning rate? In this link (wich was posted in post above yours), it says that Adam gives every free variable in the model its own learning rate:

https://spell.ml/blog/lr-schedulers-and-adaptive-optimizers-YHmwMhAAACYADm6F

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when using weight decay with the vanilla Adam optimizer, as it appears that the vanilla Adam formula is wrong when using weight decay, as pointed out in the article *Decoupled Weight Decay Regularization* https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05101 .

You should probably use the AdamW variant when you want to use Adam with weight decay.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative is to increase the batch size. A larger number of samples per update will force the optimizer to be more cautious with the updates. If GPU memory limits the number of samples that can be tracked per update, you may have to resort to CPU and conventional RAM for training, which will obviously further slow down training.

Answer (score 1):

**From another point of view**

All stochastic gradient descent (SGD) optimizers, including Adam, have randomization built and have no guarantees of reaching a global minima

After several
times of reduction, a satisfying local extremum will be obtained.
so using learning decay will not help reach global minima as it is supposed to help.

Also if you used it the learning rate will eventually become very
small, and the algorithm will become ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

I myself was wondering if ADAM optimizer requires an LR schedule or not. I read the answers by Wenmin Wu and Austin and felt like it was worth a try. I tried it in my experiment and observed significant gains. I am attaching loss plots from my experiments to share my observations. Blue curve is train_MAE, Orange curve is val_MAE (forgot to add legends :)).

[MAE loss without LR schedule, LR = 0.01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8vHt.png)

[MAE loss with LR schedule, initial_LR = 0.01 and LR_decay = 0.8 after every 5 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKFF5.png)

I know it is empirical evidence, but the point I am trying to make is that it's a good idea to try LR scheduling with ADAM, because it might improve convergence drastically.